# Character Limit when using 'Line Input #1'

Tags: ms-access, import, vba

I am working on a Microsoft Access 2002 Database.  I have a text file (from another organization) which I import into the database using 'DoCmd.TransferText' without any major issues.  I get a new file every month and occasionally the external organization which supplies the file changes the content, order and/or number of columns (as part of their own ongoing development, not randomly - I presume/hope).

I am currently trying to add some code to my VBA process which will check the layout of the file BEFORE importing the file into the database and warn me if it's changed.  I thought I could do this by using 'Line Input #1' to import the column headings to a string which I can then compare to the expected column headings.

The problem I am having is that the number of characters I feel I need to compare is 2,568 but when I use 'Line Input #1' I only seem to get the first 1023 characters so the comparison always fails.  Is there anyway I can increase/bypass the limit, or perhaps import the next 1023 characters and combine them in a string?

P.S.  The file in question does not contain any carriage returns, only line feed characters, so although it imports okay the 'Line Input #1' method will attempt to load in the whole file (only in theory, in practical terms it's obviously only doing 1023 characters) which is why I set the string length to 2,568 when declaring the variable (so that it would ignore the rest of the file).

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub FileImport()

Dim db As Database
Dim rstFiles As Recordset
Dim strFileHeaders As String * 2568 'Set Fixed length as we only want to check the first 2,568 characters of the file to confirm layout
Dim strExpectedHeaders As String * 2568

strExpectedHeaders = ";;Totals;;;Fixed Charge - Metered Water;;;;;;Volumetric Water Charge - Metered;;;Fixed Charge - Metered Waste Water;;;;;;" & _
    "Volumetric Waste Water Charge - Metered;;;Property Drainage Charge (p/£RV);;;;;;Roads Drainage Charge (p/£RV);;;;;;" & _
    "Non Domestic Metered Wastewater Fixed Charge;;;;;;Non Domestic Metered Wastewater Volume Charge;;;;;;Fixed Charge - Un-metered Water;;;;;;" & _
    "Water RV Charge - Un-metered;;;;;;Fixed Charge - Un-metered Waste Water;;;;;;Volumetric Waste Water Charge - Un-metered;;;;;;" & _
    "Supply Contract Discount (Water);;;;;;Supply Contract Discount (Waste);;;;;;Direct Debit Discount;;;;;;Water Management Charge;;;;;;;Meter Read History;;;;" & Chr(10) & _
    "Customer reference;Date posted;Bill no;Meter serial no.;From date;To date;Meter size (actual);Meter size (billed);" & _
    "Property address;Billing address;Rateable value;Your ref;PURN;Water SPID;Waste water SPID;% Return to sewer;Net total;" & _
    "VAT amount;Total amount;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;" & _
    "Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost 1;Consumption 1;Unit cost 2;Consumption 2;Unit cost 3;Consumption 3;Unit cost 4;" & _
    "Consumption 4;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;" & _
    "Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost 1;Consumption 1;Unit cost 2;Consumption 2;Unit cost 3;Consumption 3;Unit cost 4;" & _
    "Consumption 4;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;" & _
    "Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;" & _
    "VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;" & _
    "Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;" & _
    "Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Net amount;" & _
    "VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Discount;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Discount;" & _
    "Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;Days charged;Discount;Consumption;Net amount;VAT amount;Total amount;" & _
    "Days charged;Unit cost;Consumption;Measured site area;Meter serial number;Meter location;Current reading date;" & _
    "Current meter read method;Current 'Actual / Estimate';Current reading;Previous reading date;Previous 'Actual / Estimate';" & _
    "Previous reading;Previous reading date;Previous meter read method;Previous 'Actual / Estimate';Previous reading;Previous reading date;Previous 'Actual / Estimate';Previous reading;"


Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rstFiles = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [id], [filename], [path]" & _
"FROM [import file] " & _
"WHERE (((imported)=False)) ", dbOpenDynaset)

Do
    Open rstFiles![Path] & rstFiles![filename] For Input As #1
    If Not EOF(1) Then Line Input #1, strFileHeaders
    Close #1

    If strFileHeaders = strExpectedHeaders Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "BS_WWW_Spec", "import - BS WWW", rstFiles![Path] & rstFiles![filename], False, ""
    Else
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO [audit] (eventsource, eventmessage) " & _
            "VALUES (""Sub FileImport"" ,""Layout of FileID " & rstFiles![ID] & " not recognized"")", dbFailOnError
    End If

    rstFiles.MoveNext

Loop Until rstFiles.EOF

rstFiles.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `input` instead of `line input`:

```
Dim strFileHeaders As String * 2568

Open rstFiles![Path] & rstFiles![filename] For Input As #1
Input #1, strFileHeaders
Close #1
```

It works on Access 2010, I don't know if Access 2002 has more restrictive max length also on `input`.